# PHP search multiple filters

Tags: php, mysql

So I have multiple filter inputs

This is my search script

```
if(isset($_GET['sub_cat'])){
    if($_GET['sub_cat'] != ''){
            if(isset($_GET['min_range'])){
                if(isset($_GET['max_range']) && $_GET['max_range'] != ''){
                    if(isset($_GET['for_r_s'])){
                        if($_GET['for_r_s'] == 1 || $_GET['for_r_s'] == 2){
                            $query = "SELECT posts.ID, posts.ad_title, posts.ad_price, posts.ad_location, posts.ad_sub_cat FROM `posts` 
                            INNER JOIN `posts_attributes` WHERE posts.ID = posts_attributes.post_id 
                            AND `ad_title` LIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%') AND `ad_sub_cat` = ?
                            AND `ad_brand` LIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%') AND `ad_price` >= ? 
                            AND `ad_price` <= ? OR `for_r_s` = ? AND `meta_key` = 'owl_hours' AND `meta_value` >= ? AND `meta_value` <= ?"; 
                            $get_posts = $conn_posts->prepare($query);
                            $get_posts->bind_param("sssiiiii", $title, $sub_cat ,$brand, $min_range, $max_range, $for_r_s,$ad_hours_mileage_min, $ad_hours_mileage_max);  
                        }else{
                            echo "bye";
                            $query = "SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `ad_title` LIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%') AND `ad_sub_cat` = ? AND `ad_brand` 
                            LIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%') AND `ad_price` >= ? AND `ad_price` <= ?"; 
                            $get_posts = $conn_posts->prepare($query);
                            $get_posts->bind_param("sssii", $title, $sub_cat ,$brand, $min_range, $max_range);  
                        }
                    }else{
                        $query = "SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `ad_title` LIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%') AND `ad_sub_cat` = ? AND `ad_brand` 
                        LIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%') AND `ad_price` >= ? AND `ad_price` <= ?"; 
                        $get_posts = $conn_posts->prepare($query);
                        $get_posts->bind_param("sssii", $title, $sub_cat ,$brand, $min_range, $max_range);  
                    }
                }else{
                    if(isset($_GET['for_r_s'])){
                        if($_GET['for_r_s'] == 1 || $_GET['for_r_s'] == 2){
                            $query = "SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `ad_title` LIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%') AND `ad_sub_cat` = ? AND `ad_brand` 
                            LIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%') AND `ad_price` >= ? AND `for_r_s` = ?"; 
                            $get_posts = $conn_posts->prepare($query);
                            $get_posts->bind_param("sssii", $title, $sub_cat ,$brand, $min_range, $for_r_s);
                        }else{
                            $query = "SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `ad_title` LIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%') AND `ad_sub_cat` = ? AND `ad_brand` 
                            LIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%') AND `ad_price` >= ?"; 
                            $get_posts = $conn_posts->prepare($query);
                            $get_posts->bind_param("sssi", $title, $sub_cat ,$brand, $min_range);
                        }
                    }else{
                        $query = "SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `ad_title` LIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%') AND `ad_sub_cat` = ? AND `ad_brand` 
                        LIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%') AND `ad_price` >= ?"; 
                        $get_posts = $conn_posts->prepare($query);
                        $get_posts->bind_param("sssi", $title, $sub_cat ,$brand, $min_range);
                    }
                }
            }else{
                if(isset($_GET['max_range']) && $_GET['max_range'] != ''){
                    if(isset($_GET['for_r_s'])){
                        if($_GET['for_r_s'] == 1 || $_GET['for_r_s'] == 2){
                            $query = "SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `ad_title` LIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%') AND `ad_sub_cat` = ? AND `ad_brand` 
                            LIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%') AND `ad_price` <= ? AND `for_r_s` = ?"; 
                            $get_posts = $conn_posts->prepare($query);
                            $get_posts->bind_param("sssii", $title, $sub_cat ,$brand, $max_range,$for_r_s);
                        }else{
                            $query = "SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `ad_title` LIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%') AND `ad_sub_cat` = ? AND `ad_brand` 
                            LIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%') AND `ad_price` <= ?"; 
                            $get_posts = $conn_posts->prepare($query);
                            $get_posts->bind_param("sssi", $title, $sub_cat ,$brand, $max_range);
                        }
                    }else{
                        $query = "SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `ad_title` LIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%') AND `ad_sub_cat` = ? AND `ad_brand` 
                        LIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%') AND `ad_price` <= ?"; 
                        $get_posts = $conn_posts->prepare($query);
                        $get_posts->bind_param("sssi", $title, $sub_cat ,$brand, $max_range);
                    }
                }else{
                    if(isset($_GET['for_r_s'])){
                        if($_GET['for_r_s'] == 1 || $_GET['for_r_s'] == 2){
                            $query = "SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `ad_title` LIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%') AND `ad_sub_cat` = ? AND `ad_brand` 
                            LIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%') AND `for_r_s` = ?";
                            $get_posts = $conn_posts->prepare($query);
                            $get_posts->bind_param("sssi", $title, $sub_cat ,$brand, $for_r_s);
                        }else{
                            $query = "SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `ad_title` LIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%') AND `ad_sub_cat` = ? AND `ad_brand` LIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%')";
                            $get_posts = $conn_posts->prepare($query);
                            $get_posts->bind_param("sss", $title, $sub_cat ,$brand);
                        }
                    }else{
                        $query = "SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `ad_title` LIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%') AND `ad_sub_cat` = ? AND `ad_brand` LIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%')";
                        $get_posts = $conn_posts->prepare($query);
                        $get_posts->bind_param("sss", $title, $sub_cat ,$brand); 
                    }
                }
            }
    }else{
        if(isset($_GET['min_range'])){
            if(isset($_GET['max_range']) && $_GET['max_range'] != ''){
                if(isset($_GET['for_r_s'])){
                    if($_GET['for_r_s'] == 1 || $_GET['for_r_s'] == 2){
                        $query = "SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `ad_title` LIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%') AND `ad_brand` 
                        LIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%') AND `ad_price` >= ? AND `ad_price` <= ? AND `for_r_s` = ?"; 
                        $get_posts = $conn_posts->prepare($query);
                        $get_posts->bind_param("ssiii", $title, $brand, $min_range, $max_range, $for_r_s);
                    }else{
                        $query = "SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `ad_title` LIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%') AND `ad_brand` 
                        LIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%') AND `ad_price` >= ? AND `ad_price` <= ?"; 
                        $get_posts = $conn_posts->prepare($query);
                        $get_posts->bind_param("ssii", $title, $brand, $min_range, $max_range);
                    }
                }else{
                    $query = "SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `ad_title` LIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%') AND `ad_brand` 
                    LIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%') AND `ad_price` >= ? AND `ad_price` <= ?"; 
                    $get_posts = $conn_posts->prepare($query);
                    $get_posts->bind_param("ssii", $title, $brand, $min_range, $max_range);
                }
            }else{
                if(isset($_GET['for_r_s'])){
                    if( $_GET['for_r_s'] == 1 || $_GET['for_r_s'] == 2){
                        $query = "SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `ad_title` LIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%') AND `ad_brand` 
                        LIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%') AND `ad_price` >= ? AND `for_r_s` = ?"; 
                        $get_posts = $conn_posts->prepare($query);
                        $get_posts->bind_param("sssi", $title, $brand, $min_range, $for_r_s);
                    }else{
                        $query = "SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `ad_title` LIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%') AND `ad_brand` 
                        LIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%') AND `ad_price` >= ?"; 
                        $get_posts = $conn_posts->prepare($query);
                        $get_posts->bind_param("ssi", $title, $brand, $min_range);
                    }
                }else{
                    $query = "SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `ad_title` LIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%') AND `ad_brand` 
                    LIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%') AND `ad_price` >= ?"; 
                    $get_posts = $conn_posts->prepare($query);
                    $get_posts->bind_param("ssi", $title, $brand, $min_range); 
                }
            }
        }else{
            if(isset($_GET['max_range']) && $_GET['max_range'] != ''){
                if(isset($_GET['for_r_s'])){
                    if($_GET['for_r_s'] == 1 || $_GET['for_r_s'] == 2){
                        $query = "SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `ad_title` LIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%') AND `ad_brand` 
                        LIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%') AND `ad_price` <= ? AND `for_r_S` = ?"; 
                        $get_posts = $conn_posts->prepare($query);
                        $get_posts->bind_param("ssii", $title, $brand, $max_range, $for_r_s);
                    }else{
                        $query = "SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `ad_title` LIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%') AND `ad_brand` 
                        LIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%') AND `ad_price` <= ?"; 
                        $get_posts = $conn_posts->prepare($query);
                        $get_posts->bind_param("ssi", $title, $brand, $max_range); 
                    }
                }else{
                    $query = "SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `ad_title` LIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%') AND `ad_brand` 
                    LIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%') AND `ad_price` <= ?"; 
                    $get_posts = $conn_posts->prepare($query);
                    $get_posts->bind_param("ssi", $title, $brand, $max_range); 
                }
            }else{
                if(isset($_GET['for_r_s'])){
                    if($_GET['for_r_s'] == 1 || $_GET['for_r_s'] == 2){
                        $query = "SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `ad_title` LIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%') AND `ad_brand` LIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%') AND `for_r_s` = ?";
                        $get_posts = $conn_posts->prepare($query);
                        $get_posts->bind_param("ssi", $title, $brand, $for_r_s);
                    }else{
                        $query = "SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `ad_title` LIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%') AND `ad_brand` LIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%')";
                        $get_posts = $conn_posts->prepare($query);
                        $get_posts->bind_param("ss", $title, $brand); 
                    }
                }else{
                    $query = "SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `ad_title` LIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%') AND `ad_brand` LIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%')";
                    $get_posts = $conn_posts->prepare($query);
                    $get_posts->bind_param("ss", $title, $brand); 
                }
            }
        }
    }
}else{
    $sub_cat = ''; 
    if(isset($_GET['for_r_s'])){
        if($_GET['for_r_s'] == 1 || $_GET['for_r_s'] == 2){
            $query = "SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `ad_title` LIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%') AND `ad_brand` LIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%') AND `for_r_s` = ?";
            $get_posts = $conn_posts->prepare($query);
            $get_posts->bind_param("ssi", $title, $brand, $for_r_s);
        }else{
            $query = "SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `ad_title` LIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%') AND `ad_brand` LIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%')";
            $get_posts = $conn_posts->prepare($query);
            $get_posts->bind_param("ss", $title, $brand);
        }
    }else{
        $query = "SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `ad_title` LIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%') AND `ad_brand` LIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%')";
        $get_posts = $conn_posts->prepare($query);
        $get_posts->bind_param("ss", $title, $brand); 
    }
}
```

This is the Html form

```
<form action="" method="post">
                    <select name="main_cat" id="main_cat">
                        <option value="null" disabled selected>Select Category</option>
                        <?php 
                            $get_category = $conn_posts->prepare("SELECT * FROM `cats` WHERE `main_cat` = 0;");
                            $get_category->execute();
                            $get_category_results = $get_category->get_result(); // get result
                            while($row = $get_category_results->fetch_assoc()){ 
                                echo '<option value="'.$row['ID'].'">'.$row['cat_name'].'</option>';
                            }
                        ?>
                    </select>
                    </br>
                    <select name="sub_cat" id="sub-category-dropdown">
                        <option value="">Select SubCategory</option>
                    </select>
                    </br>
                    <input type="text" name="ad_brand" Placeholder="Brand(Cat,Jcb,Doosan)">
                    </br>
                    <label for="for_r_S">Price</label>
                    <div class="range_sliders">
                        <input type="text" name="min_range" Placeholder="Min">
                        <span> - </span>
                        <input type="text" name="max_range" Placeholder="Max">
                    </div>
                    </br>
                    <label for="for_r_S">For Rent</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="for_r_s" id="for_r_s" value="1">
                    <label for="for_r_S">For Sale</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="for_r_s" id="for_r_s" value="2">
                    </br>
                    <div id="content"></div>
                    <button type="submit" name="filter_button" class="filter_button">Search</button> 
                </form>
```

All $vaiables are processed and cleaned for any js/HTML tags I just didn't include that because I don't think is relevant to my question.

My Problem is it feels wrong to use this many if statement for a search is my way of processing the PHP search filter correct or is there a different/better way of doing it.

Comment: Is the code working, and you just want to simplify it? If so then you might get more help at the Code Review stackexchange (although please check their on-topic guidance before posting). Here we mainly deal with problems and bugs in code.

Comment: okay thanks, @ADyson I will check it :) have a good day/night

Comment: Before you post at [codereview.se], make sure to read [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778), as some things are done differently over there - e.g. question titles should simply say what the code *does*, as the question is always, "How can I improve this?".  Be sure that the code works correctly; include your unit tests if possible.  You'll likely get some suggestions on making it more efficient, easier to read, and better tested.